# closure-compiler wouldn't switch off suspicious code warning

Tags: java, javascript, command-line-arguments, google-closure-compiler

I use the closure compiler to compile different js files into one short file. Admittedly this is not very effective for an already compiled file but never the less it should work.
I got the command line options from the [wiki page](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/Warnings) but it still shows me the warnings.
Anyone got any idea what I might probably have done wrong?

```
java -jar googleClosureCompiler.jar --jscomp_off=suspiciousCode --js "bootstrap.min.js"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I finally found out that the warning "Suspicious Code" could be silenced with the option

```
--jscomp_off=uselessCode
```

Dam well played google!